# how to atomically claim a row or resource using UPDATE in mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, resources, atomic

i have a table of resources (lets say cars) which i want to claim atomically. I then want information about which resource I just claimed.

If there's a limit of one resource per one user, i can do the following trick:

```
UPDATE cars SET user = 'bob' WHERE user IS NULL LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE user = 'bob'
```

This way, I claim the resource atomically and then I can see which row I just claimed.

This doesn't work when 'bob' can claim multiple cars. I realize I can get a list of cars already claimed by bob, claim another one, and then `SELECT` again to see what's changed, but that feels hackish.

What I'm wondering is, is there some way to see which rows I just updated with my last UPDATE?

Failing that, is there some other trick to atomically claiming a row? I really want to avoid using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. If I do something like this:

```
1 SELECT id FROM cars WHERE user IS NULL
2 <here, my PHP or whatever picks a car id>
3 UPDATE cars SET user = 'bob' WHERE id = <the one i picked>
```

would `REPEATABLE READ` be sufficient here? In other words, could I be guaranteed that some other transactions won't claim the row my software has picked during step 2?

Comment: i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821142/atomically-mark-and-return-a-group-of-rows-in-database but it was asked about SQL server -- i can't find a mySQL equivalent

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE cars SET user = 'bob' WHERE id = 123 AND user IS NULL;
```

The update query returns the number of changed rows. If it has not updated any, you know the car has already been claimed by someone else.

Alternatively, you can use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about SELECT ... FOR UPDATE -- it's pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why there is so much misinformation in these answers, but the answer is straightforward (even if an advanced SQL topic). This is what "locking" is for in pretty much any RDBMS. The exact syntax depends on the vendor and version, and some offer syntax that tries to hide the lock from the user (typically when both the select and the update are in the same query).

For MySQL, you would first use the `SELECT ... FROM ... FOR UPDATE;` which tells the database to set an exclusive lock on each record it returns.

**Important** don't lock more rows than you absolutely need to! Make the "SELECT FOR UPDATE" query as granular as you can, with liberal usage of "WHERE" and "LIMIT" clauses.

Afterwards, when the same connection to the database issues an `UPDATE ...` on the same rows that were previously locked, that lock is released and others may access that row once more.

So let's say you have a job queue, with a field "STATUS" that is used to set the progress state of each job. 0 is for queued, 1 is for in progress, and 2 is for done, 3 is for failed, etc.

Each runner could atomically obtain a job to run (so that no two runners try to work the same job) by issuing the following:

```
SELECT ID, * FROM JOBS WHERE STATUS = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

then

```
UPDATE JOBS SET STATUS = 1 WHERE JOBS.ID = X;
```

then it can run the job, and update the database when done:

```
UPDATE JOBS SET STATUS = [2|3] WHERE JOBS.ID = X;
```

**Important**

From the MySQL documentation:

> All locks set by LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE queries are released when the transaction is committed or rolled back.

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` does not lock records if autocommit is enabled. Either disable autocommit or (preferably) using `START TRANSACTION; SELECT ... FROM ... FOR UPDATE; UPDATE ...; END TRANSACTION;`

Comment: This answer appears to be the most descriptive regarding row locking. Thanks for the important section, great info.

Comment: If you don't use SKIP LOCKED you must always test that status is 0 before processing the row. If two threads A & B access the same row: A locks, B tries to lock and waits. When A releases B is given access to the SAME row even if now it is changed. So B must ensure that status is still 0

Answer (score 1):

```
update cars  
set @id = id, user= 'bob' 
where user is null
```

is guaranteed to be atomic and @id will tell you what was the last row you updated.

Comment: this is really clever. i will certainly use this at some point, although here I think I prefer select...for update

Comment: For some reason this gives me error 1064 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615884/leasing-jobs-atomic-update-and-get-from-a-mysql-database). Is it allowed to set user-defined variables in the `SET` part of the `UPDATE`?

Comment: It seems you need to use a hack to make your suggestion work, since setting a user-variable in this way is not allowed. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615884/leasing-jobs-atomic-update-and-get-from-a-mysql-database/32617172#32617172

Comment: The fact that it actually does totally not work makes the whole answer quite less smart.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use is a [SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). This will let you do your select, know what you selected and then update those values. The lock is released when the transaction is complete.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM cars WHERE user IS NULL");

// do something with the results

mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE cars SET user = 'bob' WHERE id = <the one that was picked>");

mysqli_commit($link);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Your example is wrong, you need to append "FOR UPDATE" on the UPDATE query.Also very important: This only works with InnoDB as storage engine, not with MyISAM. Storage type can be displayed with "show table status;". You can change the storage engine with "ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = INNODB;"