# How I select a table sorted as a "Queue"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select a table sorted as a "Queue", the least recent to most recent row. Exists something feature that enable me to do this?

Comment: You need to show the table structure, and what defines it as being first...last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least, if you have an **IDENTITY/AUTONUMBER**, or at least a **DATE** to sort by you could

```
SELECT *
FORM Table
ORDER BY DateColumn
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FORM Table
ORDER BY IDColumn
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that there is no guarantee that IDENTITY columns will be in sequential order of the time at which they were inserted

Comment: Aggreed, but with no structure provided, this should cover some of th OP's possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least a column that represent a moment in time, like a date column. Then you order by that field:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY BirthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mean "ORDER BY", do you mean use a table as concurrency-safe message queue?

Like this: [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition)?