# SELECT and UPDATE table so there is no overlap of Threads

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, concurrency

Say I have the following table:

```
ID|Read
-------
 1|true
 2|false
 3|false
 4|false
```

... and I need to read the smallest ID, that has [Read] == false; plus, update that I have now read it.

So if i execute my Stored Procedure dbo.getMinID, it will return ID: 2, and update [Read] -> true.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMinID]
(
  @QueryID INT OUTPUT 
)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @QueryID = [ID] from Table
  UPDATE Table SET [Read] = 1 WHERE [ID] = @QueryID 
END
```

The problem is that I have ten (10) asynchronous Threads executing dbo.getMinID, at the same time, and I CANNOT have them select the SAME [ID] under any circumstances. I am worried that a second thread my execute between my SELECT and UPDATE statement, thus returning [ID]: 2 in both scenarios.

How can I ensure that I do not select/update the same record twice, no matter how many threads are acting upon the Stored Procedure?  ALSO, please keep in mind that the table CONSTANTLY has new rows added, so I cannot lock the table!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a concurrency safe queue type locking, then use ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST hints?

[SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition)

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT TOP 1 @QueryID = [ID] from Table WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
UPDATE Table SET [Read] = 1 WHERE [ID] = @QueryID 

COMMIT TRAN -- TRAM
```

However, in one statement. something like

```
WITH T AS
(
    --ORDER BY with TOP , or perhaps MIN is better?
    SELECT TOP 1 [Read], [ID] from Table
    WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) ORDER BY [Read]
)
UPDATE
    T
SET
    [Read] = 1;
```

Comment: will min, not trigger a lock on all rows? or am i just talking nonsense

Comment: shared lock which is readonly, and it will skip other locks because of READPAST. Does not matter, really...

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be atomic, you *must* lock something, but that doesn't mean you have to lock it *for long*. I would first try with some tightly scoped transactions, but I'd also be interested to try the update variant that does a `SELECT` at the same time :

```
UPDATE TOP (1) [foo]
SET [read] = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.id
WHERE [read] = 0
```

You could *see* if that has any concurrency issues - in honesty, I don't know without checking! You may need to add something like `WITH (ROWLOCK)`. Personally, though, I'd want to keep it simple and try a serializable transaction.

Also note that this doesn't guarantee *which* record you will get (first? last?)

Comment: I don't mind locking the ROW, just as long as i don't lock the table.

Comment: You mean SET the Transaction isolation level to serializable?

Comment: If you set the transaction level to serializable and use a transaction, you should be able to use your *original* code.

Comment: What I am unclear about is if it will lock my one row (TOP 1) or if it will lock all row with the condition [read]=0

Answer (score 1):

Make your transaction isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` and place an exclusive lock with your `SELECT` command:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @QueryID = [ID] from Table WITH (XLOCK) ORDER BY id DESC
UPDATE Table SET [Read] = 1 WHERE [ID] = @QueryID
```

This will place an `XLOCK` on the top key range and will prevent concurrent queries from reading the top record.

This way, no transactions will ever get the same record.

Answer (score 0):

put the select and update and the select statement in a transaction and in the start of the transaction lock the table so the outher threads will wait.
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: i don't want to lock the table because INSERTs are being done constantly. plus tomorrow there may be 1000 Threads running on the same table, which means i need a less-intrusive, yet explicit way of doing this.

Comment: @Theofanis - it doesn't matter *how* fast your db access is if you make a mess of the data; first try it in the simplest way (with a transaction), *then* challenge the performance.

Comment: If this is the case and the number of threads can go  up to 1000 the try adding a new null column int the table. the first thing the tread will do is write its id in the new column so no other thread will be able to take this row