# TABLOCKX versus SERIALIZABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a series of T-SQL queries that I need to run atomically. (See Below)... The purpose is to allow 1 user to retrieve a single, unique row at a time and prevent other users from retrieving the same row simultaneously.

So far I have seen two possible solutions. 1) Table Hints (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX) and 2) Transaction Isolation Level (SERIALIZABLE)...

My Questions:

1. Which option is better?
2. Is there another/better solution?

```
DECLARE @recordId int;

SELECT @recordId = MIN([id])
FROM Exceptions
WHERE [status] = 'READY';

UPDATE Exceptions
SET [status] = 'PROCESSING',
    [username] = @Username
WHERE [id] = @recordId;

SELECT *
FROM Exceptions
WHERE [id] = @recordId;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case,

- HOLDLOCK = SERIALIZABLE = duration, concurrency
- TABLOCKX = an exclusive table lock

The 2 concepts are different and neither does what you want.

To do what you want, to [avoid race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001), you need to force a non-blocking (READPAST) exclusive (UPDLOCK) row level (ROWLOCK) lock,. You can also use the OUTPUT clause to make it a single statement that will be atomic. This scales well.

```
UPDATE
    E
SET
   [status] = 'PROCESSING', [username] = @Username
OUTPUT
   INSERTED.*
FROM
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 id, [status], [username]
    FROM Exceptions (ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE [status] = 'READY'
    ORDER BY id
   ) E
```

In general, locks have 3 aspects

- Granularity = what is locked = row, page, table (`PAGLOCK, ROWLOCK, TABLOCK`)
- Isolation Level = lock duration, concurrency (`HOLDLOCK, READCOMMITTED, REPEATABLEREAD, SERIALIZABLE`)
- Mode = sharing/exclusivity (`UPDLOCK, XLOCK`)

And

- "combined" eg `NOLOCK, TABLOCKX`

Answer (score 2):

You are describing typical queue processing and neither tablockx, nor serializable are required, nor will they actually work. I recommend you go over [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) for an in dept discussion at what is possible and what not. The gist of it is:

- choose proper clustered key (critical!)
- Use OUTPUT clause
- Use READPAST