# Strange Locking Behaviour in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking

Can anyone please tell me why does the following statement inside a given stored procedure returns repeated results even with locks on the rows used by the first `SELECT` statement?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( ID INT )

INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE SomeValue <= 10
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE SomeValue >= 5

SELECT * FROM @Temp

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Any values in `SomeTable` for which `SomeValue` is between 5 and 10 will be returned twice, even though they were locked in the first `SELECT`. I thought that locks were in place for the whole transaction, and so I wasn't expecting the query to return repeated results. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same session/transaction, READPAST won't have any effect.

So even though you have ROWLOCK and UPDLOCK for the first SELECT , the next SELECT ignores these. If the 2nd SELECT was a different session, then it'd work as expected.

See these for more info: [ORDER BY and WITH(ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388900/order-by-and-withrowlock-updlock-readpast/6390191#6390191) and [TABLOCKX versus SERIALIZABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924861/tablockx-versus-serializable/4924999#4924999)