# SQL Server 2000 - Update rows and return updated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am wondering how to rewrite the following SQL Server 2005/2008 script for SQL Server 2000 which didn't have `OUTPUT` yet.

Basically, I would like to update rows and return the updated rows without creating deadlocks.

Thanks in advance!

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Locked = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE Locked = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't in SQL Server 2000 cleanly

What you can do is use a transaction and some lock hints to prevent a race condition.  Your main problem is 2 processes accessing the same row(s), not a deadlock. See [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001) for more, please.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM TABLE WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK) WHERE Locked = 0

UPDATE TABLE
SET Locked = 1
WHERE Locked = 0

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I haven't tried this, but you could also try a SELECT in an UPDATE trigger from INSERTED.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I also added the link from the original thread for reference. http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1257