# tsql: stored procedure and rowlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a concurrency in a multiple user system and a stored procedure as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetWorkitemID
AS
DECLARE @workitem int;

UPDATE workqueue
SET status = 'InProcess', @workitem = workitemid
WHERE workitemid = (SELECT TOP 1 workitemid
FROM workqueue WITH (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,READPAST)
WHERE status = 'New' ORDER BY workitemid)

SELECT @workitem

GO
```

It updates a single record status from 'New' to 'InProcess' and returns record's ID.

The questions are as follows: Should I use this stored procedure in a transaction scope to enable ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK etc.? Is it required? And the second: Is it really thread safe and guarantee uniqueness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is the correct way to run "table as a queue" 
  See this please: [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001)
- You don't need a transaction
- This is both thread and concurrency safe

Edit:

As a counter example to Filip De Vos's

Note the use of an covering index *and* UPDLOCK not XLOCK *and* the same query

```
DROP table locktest
create table locktest (id int, workitem int, status varchar(50))
insert into locktest (id, workitem) values (1, 1), (2,2), (3,3)
create index ix_test2 on locktest(workitem) INCLUDE (id, status)

--When I run this on one connection
begin tran 
select top (1) id, status 
from locktest with (rowlock, updlock, readpast) 
ORDER BY workitem
```

... I get expected results in another connection with the same query

Comment: your original answer by the link?

Comment: @Johnny: yes, but I've added stuff based on your other questions

Answer (score 2):

It is not reliable. Because the locking hints you gave are just that, locking hints. Additionally, depending on the way the table is indexed the results might be very different.

For example:

```
create table test (id int, workitem int, status varchar(50))
insert into test (id, workitem) values (1, 1), (2,2), (3,3)
create index ix_test on test(workitem)
```

When I run this on one connection

```
begin tran 
select * from test with (rowlock, xlock, holdlock) where workitem = 1
```

And I run this on a second connection:

```
select top (1) * from test with (rowlock, readpast) order by workitem
```

This returns:

```
workitem
--------
3
```

Same if i do:

```
update top (1) test with (rowlock, readpast)
set status = 'Proc' 
output inserted.workitem
```

So, you can use this to concurrent pick up what you need, but this is not a reliable way to have in-order concurrent processing.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use this stored procedure in a transaction scope...

Every DML statement in SQL runs in the context of a transaction, whether you explicitly open one or not. By default, when executing each statement, SQL server will open a transaction if one is not open, execute the statement, and then commit the transaction (if no error occurred) or roll it back.

Subject to the caveat mention by @Filip (that there's still no guarantee on the order in which items will be selected), it will be safe and each invocation will return a different row, if one is available and not locked.