# Locking assistance required

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, locking

I have a stored procedure that `SELECT`s the `TOP 1` record from the table and assigns some variables with the values of the columns.  It then `SELECT`s 10 records where the `Id` column has the same value as the `TOP 1` variable column.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Id = [Id]
  FROM [TableA]
 ORDER
    BY [DateCreated], [Priority]

SELECT TOP 10 *
  FROM [TableA]
 WHERE [Id] = @Id;
```

The purpose is to `SELECT` one record, and then get 10 matchings records to process.  This works if one connection is calling the stored procedure.  I have an application which is multi-threaded and this then causes a problem, because, if the first and second records are the same `Id`, I'd like them to be in one result set so that the second thread will pick up a different value.  Here is where I have the problem.  I've tried to use `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK` hints on the first `SELECT` statement, but that locks the first record and allows another thread to pick up the next value which I'd like in the first thread.  I have also started a `TRANSACTION` within the stored procedure and changed the `ISOLATION LEVEL` to `READ COMMITTED`, but the second thread is always getting in and taking that next value before the first thread can `SELECT` the 10 records where the `Id`s match.

Does anyone have anyone have any ideas on how I should go about this?  Is this approach possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition)

Comment: What ORDER BY should apply to the queries? What does the full code look like? What does the table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems odd: selecting from the same table, TOP without ORDER BY etc.

In the absence of any other information and assuming you want to keep the same solution, you'd have to use a semaphore solution with [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). This will serialise access through your code: a 2nd process can wait or timeout etc depending how you set the parameters