# Duplicate Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a duplicate record problem; concurrency issue. I'm retrieving the record from database:

```
SELECT TOP 1 certid, certiname
  FROM certificate
 WHERE issued = 0
   AND year = 2011
```

After retrieving the record I'm inserting the record different table by using a procedure...

There are multiple tables affecting that reason. I also used SQL transaction either affected all transaction or none, `commit` or `Rollback`. In this procedure I am also updating a certificate

```
UPDATE certificate
SET    issued = 1
WHERE  certid = @certid
```

but same certificate issued more than one policy..

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. I have a vague idea that you are trying to [use a table as a queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) but this is difficult/impossible to follow.

Comment: The word is 'record'. It is not 'recored' or 'reocord'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have concurrent processes select one row each without overlap, then you need some hints `(ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)`. More info here: [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001)

If you want to select/update in the same transaction, use the OUTPUT clause

```
UPDATE TOP (1) certificate WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)
SET    issued = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.certid, INSERTED.certiname
-- or OUTPUT INSERTED.certid, INSERTED.certiname INTO @SOmeTableVariable 
WHERE  issued = 0
   AND year = 2011
```

Comment: thanx dude... can u tel me how i can set OUTPUT INSERTED.certid, INSERTED.certiname to local variable because this statement always updating top 1 record when will be my certificate has over that this statement nothing will be update .. it's  reason i want to store value to local variable

Comment: @AbrarAhmad: you'd need to load a table variable, then select from that or join to it.

Answer (score 0):

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type='U' and name='Temp_Table1')
begin
Drop table Temp_Table1
end
go
select * into Temp_Table1 from Table1
go 
TRUNCATE TABLE Temp_Table1
go
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unqT ON Temp_Table1(id DESC) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY
go
INSERT INTO Temp_Table1 SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY  id DESC 
go

TRUNCATE TABLE Table1
go
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Temp_Table1