# Select then update a record in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to select a record in sql and then update it, all in one statement or stored procedre.

So, I have this statement:

```
select top 1 ID, TimeStamp, Locked, Deleted 
from TableName 
where Locked='False' and Deleted='False' 
order by TimeStamp asc
```

How can I select that statement and then set Locked='True' to the returning record.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to select it? Are you looking to display the record BEFORE changing it or display the record AFTER changing it?

Comment: If it's SQL Server use an UPDATE with an OUTPUT Statement

Comment: Start transaction. select. update. commit.

Comment: I'm looking to select it then lock if immediately afterwards.

Comment: This is more complex than you would guess.  Problem is update does not support top. Please post some test data and desired output.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338306/sql-threadsafe-update-top-1-for-fifo-queue/49339468#comment85681208_49339468

Comment: Actually you want a prior lock.  You want the read to take and update lock so it cannot get changed before YOU change it.

Answer (score 3):

if you use the output clause, you can see the updated record before it was updated by selecting from `deleted`

```
with cte as (
    select  top 1 
            ID, 
            TimeStamp, 
            Locked, 
            Deleted 
    from    TableName 
    where   Locked='False' and Deleted='False' 
    order by TimeStamp asc
)
update  cte 
set     Locked = 'True'
output  deleted.*
```

Comment: There is a (small) window where value(s) could be changed between the read and the write.

Comment: @paparazzo how so? The CTE doesnt actually get materialized until the update is called.  How much time we talking about?  It shouldnt be any different that using a derived table.   I think you're reading too much into what OP is saying.. I believe when they say `then lock if immediately afterwards` they just mean set Locked=True.. not actually lock the record

Comment: Why leave a small window open.  See my answer.

Comment: @paparazzo Its not really a window.. you're updating in a single statement and displaying the output.. what window are you talking about?  check out this query  `WITH T(X) AS (SELECT NEWID())SELECT * FROM T T1 JOIN T T2 ON T1.X=T2.X`  if the cte is executed before the select, you should get a result

Comment: See my first comment. Not going to argue with you. If you don't think I am correct then fine.

Comment: Oh my.. you're talking about the time it takes between finding the top 1 and updating it.. in the same transaction? have fun worrying about that

Comment: The fun is over.  See my answer.

Comment: @paparazzo can you fix your answer so we can actually look at it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it locked then I think this will do it.
Problem is you cannot use `top` with `update`.

```
create table #T (pk int identity primary key, ts timestamp not null, lock bit not null)
insert into #T (lock) values (1), (0), (1), (0), (0);
select * 
from #T t
order by t.ts asc;

update tt 
set tt.lock = 1 
output deleted.*
from ( select top(1) t.* 
       from #T t with (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) 
       where t.lock = 0 
       --and t.Deleted = 0
       order by t.lock
     ) tt;

select * 
from #T t
order by t.ts asc;

drop table #T
```

By taking the UPDLOCK the value(s) cannot be changed between the read and the write.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to return the data out or just update it?

If it's just update:

```
Update Tablename
   Set Locked  = 'True'
 Where Locked  = 'False' 
   and Deleted = 'False'
```

To give the result out:(add this after the udpate)

```
select top 1 ID, TimeStamp, Locked, Deleted 
  from TableName 
 where Locked  = 'True' 
   and Deleted = 'False' 
 order by TimeStamp asc
```