# Are these SQL Server procedures concurrency safe?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table which contains units of work:

```
create table [dbo].[Queue]
(
    [QueueId] bigint not null identity(1,1),
    [UserId] bigint default null, -- irrelevant foreign key here
    primary key clustered ([QueueId] asc)
);
go
```

A pack of workers keeps circling this table and grabs one or more units of work by changing the `UserId` field from `null` to a positive value. No two workers should be able to update the same `QueueId` at the same time and they should not wait *(readpast should help with that)*.

The following method makes it easy to add work to the table:

```
/**
* Push some work units.
* (rewritten from basic while insert to @Larnu's Tally suggestion)
*/
create procedure [dbo].[spPushWork]
    @Count int
as
begin
    if @Count < 1 or @Count > 1000000 throw 50001, N'@Count must be 1-1M.', 1;

    with [num] as
    (
        select [num] from (values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) [num]([num])
    ), [tally] as
    (
        select top (@Count)
            row_number() over (order by (select null)) as [ind]
        from [num] [num1]
            cross join [num] [num2]
            cross join [num] [num3]
            cross join [num] [num4]
            cross join [num] [num5]
            cross join [num] [num6]
    )
    merge into [dbo].[queue]
    using (select [ind] from [tally]) [t]
    on 1 = 0
    when not matched then insert default values;
end
go
```

And now we have 2 methods to grab work.

**Method #1** is thread safe *(I hope)* as it's a select-update combo:

```
/**
* This grabs work units in a single operation (Select + Update).
*/
create procedure [dbo].[spGrabSafe]
    @UserId bigint
    ,@Count int = 1
as
begin
    if @UserId < 1 throw 50001, N'@UserId must be 1+.', 1;
    if @Count < 1 throw 50001, N'@Count must be 1+.', 2;

    declare @Ids table ([Id] bigint not null);

    -- fetch and claim via single query
    with [cte] as
    (
        select top(@Count) [QueueId]
        from [dbo].[Queue] with (readpast) -- skip locked
        where [UserId] is null
        order by [QueueId] asc
    )
    update [q]
    set [UserId] = @UserId
    output [inserted].[QueueId] into @Ids
    from [dbo].[Queue] [q]
    join [cte] on [cte].[QueueId] = [q].[QueueId];

    select [Id] from @Ids;
end;
go
```

**Method #2** does the same thing as method one in 2 operations by first locking the rows and then claiming them by changing the `UserId`. It also has a delay argument that allows us to make it run longer for testing:

```
/**
* This grabs work units in multiple operations (Select&lock + Update).
*/
create procedure [dbo].[spGrabUnsafe]
    @UserId bigint
    ,@Count int = 1
    ,@Delay time = null
as
begin
    if @UserId < 1 throw 50001, N'@UserId must be 1+.', 1;
    if @Count < 1 throw 50001, N'@Count must be 1+.', 1;

    declare @Ids table ([Id] bigint not null);

    begin transaction
        -- fetch the QueueId's
        insert into @Ids
        select top(@Count) [QueueId] 
        from [dbo].[Queue]
        with (xlock, rowlock, readpast) -- lock rows + skip locked
        where [UserId] is null
        order by [QueueId] asc;

        -- claim via UserId
        update [q]
        set [UserId] = @UserId
        from [dbo].[Queue] [q]
        join @Ids [ids] on [ids].[Id] = [q].[QueueId];

        -- this allows to wait a bit to test concurrency
        if @Delay is not null
        begin
            declare @Time varchar(12) = convert(varchar, @Delay, 114);
            waitfor delay @Time;
        end;
    commit transaction;

    select [Id] from @Ids;
end
go
```

Is method #2 safe in a concurrent environment? There is a gap between selecting and updating `UserId`. But the rows should be locked...

Comment: Why use a `WHILE` to generate the numbers? That's an *awfully* slow way to do it.

Comment: @Larnu It's a helper to easily put in some data for tests. The real tables are way more complex. But it all boils down to changing the `UserId`.

Comment: But a `WHILE` is still an awfully slow way. A Tally would be hugely faster, and would `INSERT` all the rows in a single batch; locking the underlying table for a far far shorter period of time.

Comment: Why a `WHILE` is a bad idea: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07f04efb8e0fdbd4e707a20be7c73fcb)

Comment: @Larnu I don't usually need to insert empty data like this but this trick is nice!

Comment: @CodeAngry you're trying to implement a queue on top of a table. If you search SO (eg for `T-SQL queue table`) you'll find many implementations and later questions that run up against one problem or another (been there....). The only *safe* way to implement queues is by destructive reading (`DELETE Queue OUTPUT.....`) the way [Remus Rusanu](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) describes them.

Comment: BTW `MERGE` isn't atomic which means posting work can mess with the queue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001) shows Method #3 on how to "dequeue" with a single `UPDATE`, eg `UPDATE TOP (20)
    foo
SET
    ProcessorID = @PROCID
FROM
    OrderTable foo WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)
WHERE
    ProcessorID = 0` but even that can lead to race conditions eventually

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The insert is irrelevant. It's just there to fill some data easily if anyone want tot test. The RR article is a decade old. Maybe something new has come up since then. I tested 100 threads on the first version and many iterations and it never failed while getting it to deadlock was easy with poorly handled concurrency.

Comment: Consider Service Broker. Microsoft implemented this specifically to lift some of the burden of getting safe, well-performing queuing implementations from application writers.