# Hold Lock During Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have very some legacy old transactional tables which contains columns `Locked` and `LockDate`. Only one user can pick a transaction(row) at a time. Whenever user pick a speecfic transaction, we are marking the row `Locked=1` so no other user can pick the same transaction(until user save the transaction or we clear the lock after some time). The problem is that under system load, multiple user can pick the same transaction under concurrency. We are doing,

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE WHERE Locked=0 AND OurConditions
UPDATE TABLE SET Locked=1 WHERE ID=....
```

How to fix this issue with minimal performance impect on system.

Comment: You don''t implement checkin/checkout functionality by holding locks. That's going to decimate scalability without solving the concurrency problems. Transactions and *locks* are meant to be short-lived.

Comment: You can use an `UPDATE WHERE` is you want to ensure only one connection at a time can checkout/lock. Why is `TOP 1` used though? Are you trying to implement a *queue*? That's a very different *and* very difficult problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wanna simple one user get one transaction at a time for processing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `locked` to your `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE YT
SET Locked = 1--, other columns to set
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.ID = @ID
  AND Locked = 0;
```

Then someone else can't lock the "row" when it's already locked.

Comment: Means even under multiple concurrent requests only one will get the lock

Comment: @user960567 the `UPDATE WHERE` ensures that. Why did you use that `TOP 1` though? Are you trying to implement a queue? That's a far harder problem

Comment: Yes, @user960567 because as the `UPDATE` is processed the row/table will be locked. A second `UPDATE` won't be able to be processed until that first lock is released, and as the underlying data has then changed, the `UPDATE` won't return any rows in the `WHERE`; thus won't be updated.

Comment: @Larnu using `Locked` and `locks` in this context isn't a good choice as *database* locks aren't used. The row will be flagged/checked out even if the connection closes

Comment: Under concurrency how do I know which one is updated and which one not?

Comment: Not sure I follow you there, @PanagiotisKanavos . it's the table locked that helps the desired behaviour.

Comment: @user960567 I assume you're setting the name of the person who locked it in the table, so you'd know by looking at that column.

Comment: If no record updated then I need to select another ID? I am giving user one transaction to one user

Comment: Then what you're after is a queueing system, as @PanagiotisKanavos asked you  about in both this answer and question, which you haven't responded to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you suggest for selecting one transaction per user at time?

Comment: @user960567 don't use a database table in the first place. If you have to, use a *separate* queue table and use destructive dequeuing using DELETE OUTPUT, [as shown here](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). If you try to implement queues with UPDATE and locking [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001) you'll find that normal access to the table will cause problems with the queueing scenario in rare conditions, which occur at midnight or when you're on vacation